# Show tooltip using Javascript or jQuery on Span Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show tool-tip on span tag.

```
<span class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">*</span>
```

The jQuery Code That I have done

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
 });
</script>
```

But this is not running. Any Help appreciated in advance.

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: The `tooltip()` function is under the jQuery UI package but **NOT** the jQuery package. Have you injected the jQuery UI package in your codes yet?

Comment: uncaught typeerror $ is not a function @Satpal

Comment: Tried your code at https://jsbin.com (don't miss to add the jquery-library above). Works well, if you add (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js). So I think you miss do add JQuery-UI , which is an additional Library for JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have loaded `jquery` and `jquery-ui` scripts:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">* Hover</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remeber to inject all the dependency / packages needed for your application.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js""></script>
```